# Vertically align multi-paragraph text within a div

Tags: html, css

I want to align multi-paragraph of text vertically within a div. Here are my codes.

**HTML**

```
<div class="valign">
    <h3>Title of the paragraph</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>Next paragraph</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.valign {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 200px;
}
```

But it doesn't work. Your solution is welcome.

Comment: set direction to column ?

Comment: no, from top to bottom not like a column

Comment: so set direction to column

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/td24wq8h/4/

Comment: and please take the time to read this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/8620333

Comment: That doesn't work. That you for the link but it's not the same.

Comment: what is not working ? in the code I provided, the text in centred vertically and horizontally within the div

Comment: In fact, it doesn't look like what i'am expecting. I would like to get rid of the big line-spacing between the paragraph.

Comment: this is called margin, so remove margin from p and h3

Comment: Oh i see, thank you @Temani Afif